# How to update product attribute with different values in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom

I've created custom product attribute which is set on `catalog_product_save_before` event. Now i want to update value (i have two options of this value) of this attribute for all product, depends on few conditions . How can i do this? The fastest possible method. I can loop through all products and call `$product->save()`. But i was wondering if there is faster method?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mass update product attributes, use `updateAttributes` method, which is faster and better than looping through all the products and save each one of them.

Inject the model class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action` in your Observer class and 
add the code below to update your product attributes

```
// $productIds is an array of product Ids array(1,2,3,...)
// $attrData is an array of product attributes array('attribute_code1','attribute_code2'...)
// $storeId - you can use the store scope that you wish to update these product attributes

$this->productMassAction->updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId);
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, i've already tried this method, but my attribute is drop down and has two options (let say 'yes' and 'no'). I want some products to have this attribute set to 'yes' and other products should have this attribute set to 'no'. I think i can assign one value to all products using this method.

Comment: @SebastianT you can still use this method for quicker updates.  In your case. at first prepare the list of products where you want to set this attribute as 'Yes' or 1 , just use the updateAttributes method to save these products (product ids) with the attribute value as 'yes'  and then do the same for the list of products where you want to set this attribute as 'No' or 0.

Comment: you are absolutely right :D I was wondering if there is a method which loop through all products and in this loop do some conditions. But your answer is 100% correct and very simple! Thanks.

Comment: @SebastianT glad it was helpful.